# Is it possible to change the Bytes Per Cluster on an NTFS drive without reformatting?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a drive where I'm doing some performance testing with a series of small files. In my current test, I have 150,000 files averaging at 11kB, and another 150,000 files averaging at 2kB. The total size of these combined files is 5.14GB, but the size on disk is 18.3GB. Normally this wouldn't be an issue as space is pretty cheap, but I have quite a few of these tests, and need to keep as many of these files in as many of these tests as possible.

The current Bytes Per Cluster (found by running fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo (drive letter)) is set to 64kB, and I know I can decrease this value to eliminate some of the disk overhead.

My question is this: can I change the Bytes Per Cluster value without reformatting the drive? I've found there are 3rd party tools to do what I'm asking, but given the environment where this is occuring, using a 3rd party tool would be a less than ideal solution.

Thank you for your time

Comment: without 3rd party tools.  No!  Nothing built-in to windows can do it.  If there is free space, and you were using the server version equivalent to Windows 10 you could shrink the partition inside of disk management.  Then you could create another drive, and format it with the desired cluster size.

Comment: Given the very small amount of data we are talking about, creating a new NTFS file system on a thumb drive, copying the files there then copying them back to the original (but formatted) drive would be quicker than most in place conversion methods (and you would get less disk fragmentation).